# Convert a complex plain object to Realm object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, realm

I'm trying to either convert and/or pass directly a received plain javascript object to Realm Object, but I'm having trouble doing that.

"settings" - the received plain object (Realm Object converted to Json and back)

```
realm.create('Settings', {
    Id: settings.Id,
    User: settings.User,
    FavoriteChannels: settings.FavoriteChannels,
}, true)
```

Here's a simple example schema:

```
exports.Settings = {
    name: 'Settings',
    primaryKey: 'Id',
    properties: {
        Id: 'string',
        User: 'User',       
        FavoriteChannels: 'Channel[]',
    }
};

exports.User = {
    name: 'User',
    primaryKey: 'Id',
    properties: {
        Id: 'string',
        FirstName: 'string?',
        LastName: 'string?',            
        PhoneNumbers: 'PhoneNumber[]'           
    }
};

exports.PhoneNumber = {
    name: 'PhoneNumber',
    primaryKey: 'Id',
    properties: {
        Id: 'string',        
        Number: 'string',
    }
};

exports.Channel = {
    name: 'Channel',
    primaryKey: 'Id',
    properties: {
        Id: 'string',           
        ChannelName: 'string?',         
        Users: 'User[]',            
    }
};
```

If I try to pass "settings" directly in "realm.create", I get the following error:

"`User.PhoneNumbers` must be of type `'PhoneNumber[]'`, got `'object' ([object Object]`)

It expects an array, but the plain object's collections are deserialized to objects/dictionary? (ex. `PhoneNumbers: { '0': [Object] })`. There's no way for the deserializer to know how to parse Realm Object's `"List {}"` (ex. `[PhoneNumbers]: List { [0]: [Object] })` to arrays.

Realm seems to lack "symmetry" for these kinds of operations, unless I'm missing something out.

Comment: How are you converting it to JSON? And why are you pulling it all out, then putting it all back? I assume you pull it out, update a value, then push it back in? If so, why not just update the original object inside a write and skip all the converting?

Comment: You can convert it to JSON with simple JSON.stringify(). 
As for the data, let me put it that way - the server sends out the realm object over socket (which serializes & deserializes the data) to the client, then the client can make a change and send it back to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve it, would be to simply use object constructors on the client side, for example:

```
//file "dataModel.js"
export function Settings(obj) {
    this.Id = obj.Id;
    this.User = new User(obj.User); //check for null, if property in the schema is nullable, so you don't pass empty objects to Realm - example: obj.User ? new User(obj.User) : null;
    this.FavoriteChannels = Object.values(obj.FavoriteChannels).map(m => new Channel(m));
}

export function User(obj) {
    this.Id = obj.Id;
    this.FirstName = ojb.FirstName;
    this.LastName = obj.LastName;
    PhoneNumbers = Object.values(obj.PhoneNubmers).map(m => new PhoneNumber(m));
}

export function PhoneNumber(obj) {
    this.Id = obj.Id;
    this.Nubmer = obj.Number;
}

export function Channel(obj) {
    this.Id = obj.Id;
    this.ChannelName = obj.ChannelName;
    this.Users = Object.values(obj.Users).map(m => new User(m));
}


//file app.js
import * as dataModel from 'path-to-dataModel';
...
//receive data from server and create Settings using the constructor from dataModel
const testObj = new dataModel.Settings(plainSettingsObjectFromServer);  
//make any changes to the testObj and send it back to server
```

Now we can pass the plain object, received from the client, to Realm.Create:

```
realm.create('Settings', {
    Id: plainSettingsObject.Id,
    User: plainSettingsObject.User,
    FavoriteChannels: plainSettingsObject.FavoriteChannels,
}, true)
```